# Are there any scholarly critiques about Ray Bradbury's book, "The Illustrated Man"

Tags: books, literary-analysis, ray-bradbury, the-illustrated-man

I've been searching for a while over critiques or reviews that focus on *The Illustrated Man*, and there aren't too many. I've already found a couple resources through my University's library. Does anybody know or have access to critiques about this book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["the illustrated man" Bradbury](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22the%20illustrated%20man%22%20bradbury&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=1,28) - at Google Scholar

Example:

[August Derleth, 1952](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/371850?uid=3739520&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21103399130753):

> ... Unquestionably in top place among contemporary American writers of sci- ence-fiction is Ray
>   Bradbury, whose two collections, The Martian Chronicles and The Illustrated Man, stand head
>   and shoulders above all other science-fiction in our time.

Heinlein wept.

Answer (score 2):

There is an extensive "study guide" for Bradbury's 'Illustrated Man' available online [here](http://thebestnotes.com/booknotes/Illustrated_Man_Bradbury/Illustrated_Man_Study_Guide01.html).

It contains a synopsis of each chapter as well as;

- **Literary Elements**
- **Character Analysis**
- **Plot Structure Analysis**
- **Theme Analysis**
- **Author's Style**
- **Important Quotations / Quotes and Analysis of Symbolism**
- **Motifs / Imagery / Symbols**

and

- **Key Facts**

There's also a [teacher's guide](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Illustrated-Man-Lesson-Plans-ebook/dp/B0099V4CVO/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1390742126&sr=8-2&keywords=%22the%20illustrated%20man%22%20AND%20%22study%20guide%22) (including Lesson plans) although it's behind a £10 paywall.